# Angular 6, Identityserver 4 intermittent login failure

Tags: angular6, identityserver4

For a while now I have been observing a rather strange behaviour from my application.
I have an Angular frontend and an Identityserver4 implementation for authentication and authorisation. I am doing my development using VS 2017. The login process goes through smoothly or so it seems then just when you expect to hit the home screen you get the unauthorized screen instead. Other times everything works without a glitch. On other occasions I will have to try for as much as 15 times or more before i get a successfully login

Answer (score 0):

Setting this "max_id_token_iat_offset_allowed_in_seconds" to a value of "1000" solved this issue for me. Not so sure if it is the best as it appears to have security implications